# Single Sign-On using Microsoft Account to login through Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

Hi am trying Microsoft Single Sign-on authentication to my Login page.For that i have used to create Azure  multi-tenant directories and created Application with redirect-URI as per given link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-ad-authentication-for-mvc-web-application/ .
Successfully integrated the code, while running i am getting microsoft sign on page after enter the username and password i am getting below error.

**Error :**
AADSTS50020: User account 'xxxxxx@outlook.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'SampleApp' and cannot access the application 'xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx'( in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Answer (score 0):

The 'outlook.com' is a personal account. You need to set your App Registration to use v2 endpoint to access personal account.

The Microsoft document which can help you is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest) .i.e., to force Azure AD to issue V2 access token  we can  set in its app manifest `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` value to 2.0

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_8e4lSceqapNKEGF&Q_CHL=gl
>